# The proof of the kernel and cokernel formula of a certain map.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exact-sequence

If I have the following map:

$\phi_s: \mathbb Z_{p^a} \rightarrow \Bbb Z_{p^b}$ defined by multiplication by $kn/d$ where $n = p^b$ and $d = \gcd(p^a, p^b)$ and $k= p^s$ and $0 \leq k < d$ and I know that if $a\geq b$ and we are not in the case of the zero homomorphism i.e. we took $s = b -1$, we will have:

1- ker $\phi_{s} = Z_{p^{a-s+1}}.$

2- coker  $\phi_s = Z_{p^{a-s}}.$

How can I start proving the above results about the kernel and cokernel, should I use the properties of SES or what? could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the formula you have is not right. Consider the case where $a=b$ and $s=0$. Then $n=d$ and $k=1$, so the map you've defined is the identity map and hence has trivial kernel and cokernel, but your formula would give its kernel to be $\mathbb{Z}/p^{a+1}$ and its cokernel to be $\mathbb{Z}/p^a$.

If you don't mind, I'll use the notation $\phi_s$ for what you refer to by $k\Lambda$. So $\phi_s$ takes $\overline{1}\in\mathbb{Z}/p^a$ to $\overline{p^{s+b}/d}\in\mathbb{Z}/p^b$, where $d=\gcd(p^a,p^b)$. Note that the only positive divisors of $p^a$ and $p^b$ are powers of $p$, so in fact $d=p^{\min\{a,b\}}$, and we can write $\phi_s(\overline{1})=\overline{p^{s+b-\min\{a,b\}}}$. To see that $\phi_s$ is a well-defined map, you need to show that $p^a\phi_s(\overline{1})=\overline{0}\in\mathbb{Z}/p^b$. This amounts to showing that $p^ap^{s+b-{\min\{a,b\}}}$ is divisible by $p^b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, ie that $a+s+b-\min\{a,b\}\geqslant b$. Since $s\geqslant 0$, this is clear.

Now, $\overline{n}\in\ker\phi_s$ if and only if $\overline{0}=\phi_s(\overline{n})=\overline{n{p^{s+b-\min\{a,b\}}}}\in\mathbb{Z}/p^b$, which is in turn true if and only if $np^{s+b-\min\{a,b\}}$ is divisible by $p^b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. If $p^k$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $n$, then this is true if and only if $k+s+b-\min\{a,b\}\geqslant b$, ie if and only if $k+s\geqslant\min\{a,b\}$. You are assuming that $\phi_s$ is not the zero map, so we know $s<\min\{a,b\}$. Thus a generator for $\ker\phi_s$ is given by $\overline{p^{\min\{a,b\}-s}}$. The order of $\overline{p^{\min\{a,b\}-s}}$ is $p^{a-(\min\{a,b\}-s)}=p^{a+s-\min\{a,b\}}$, and subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic, so $\fbox{$\ker\phi_s\cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{a+s-\min\{a,b\}}$}$. In particular, in the case you brought up, where $b\leqslant a$ and $s=b-1$, we have $\ker\phi_s\cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{a-1}$.

Now, the cokernel of $\phi_s$ is the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}/p^b$ by the image of $\phi_s$. Quotients of cyclic groups are cyclic, and cyclic groups are uniquely determined by their cardinalities, so the cokernel of $\phi_s$ will be determined by its size. Now, by the first isomorphism theorem, the image of $\phi_s$ is isomorphic to the quotient $\frac{\mathbb{Z}/p^a}{\ker\phi_a}$. Since $|\mathbb{Z}/p^a|=p^a$, and $|\ker\phi_s|=p^{a+s-\min\{a,b\}}$ by the computation above, we have $$|\operatorname{im}\phi_s|=\frac{p^a}{p^{a+s-\min\{a,b\}}}=p^{\min\{a,b\}-s}.$$ (Again, you are assuming $s<\min\{a,b\}$, so this number makes sense.) Since $|\mathbb{Z}/p^b|=p^b$, we can hence compute $$|\operatorname{coker}(\phi_s)|=\frac{|\mathbb{Z}/p^b|}{|\operatorname{im}\phi_s|}=\frac{p^b}{p^{\min\{a,b\}-s}}=p^{b+s-\min\{a,b\}},$$ and so $\fbox{$\operatorname{coker}\phi_s\cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{b+s-\min\{a,b\}}$}$. In particular, in the case you brought up, where $b\leqslant a$ and $s=b-1$, we have $\operatorname{coker}\phi_s\cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{b-1}$.

Comment: So you corrected my formula and proved the problem in case of your new formula?

Comment: @Math yes, exactly :) ... let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: ok, thank you! just give me sometime (1 or 2 days) to read your answer thoroughly and ask you if I have questions(if you do not mind) and then I will accept it and give it the bounty.

Comment: @Math absolutely, take your time!! no rush at all

Comment: Thanks another time! :)

Comment: I do not understand why to show well definedness of $\phi_s$ I need to show that   "you need to show that $\overline{p^a}\phi_s(\overline{1})=\overline{0}\in\mathbb{Z}/p^b$." could you please explain this?

Comment: I asked this question about your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3945290/proving-that-a-function-is-well-defined just in case you want to answer it.

Comment: @Math oh, sorry for the late response – missed your message last night!! to answer your question, $\mathbb{Z}/p^a$ is a group generated by the element $\overline 1$ subject to the relation $p^a\overline 1=\overline 0$. so, to define a map $\psi$ from $\mathbb{Z}/p^a$ to any other (eg, abelian) group $G$, we need to choose an element $g\in G$ to send $\overline 1$ to under $\psi$. however, we can't just choose any element; because $p^a\overline 1$ is equal to the identity in $\mathbb{Z}/p^a$, we need $p^a g$ to equal the identity in $G$. that's all I was checking there. does this make sense? :)

Comment: No problem. Are you saying that well defined map between $\mathbb Z_{p}$ groups means that the map should take the identity to the identity? is that the meaning of well defined map between $\mathbb Z_p$ groups?

Comment: @Math ah, sorry if this wasn't clear in my answer. here's what I'm getting: suppose we want to define a map $\phi$ from $\mathbb{Z}\big/n$ to $\mathbb{Z}\big/m$, for some $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. we have that $\overline{1}$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}\big/n$, so it suffices to choose $\phi(\overline{1})\in\mathbb{Z}\big/m$. however, we cannot just choose any element; since $\overline{1}$ has order $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}\big/ n$, $\phi(\overline{1})$ must have order dividing $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}\big/m$. this is because group homomorphisms must respect any "relations" that hold in their domain...

Comment: ...in particular, since $n\overline{1}=\overline{0}$ in $\mathbb{Z}\big/n$, we must have also that $n\phi(\overline{1})=\phi(n\overline{1})=\phi(\overline{0})=\overline{0}$ in $\mathbb{Z}\big/m$ before we can define a group homomorphism by extending $\overline{1}\mapsto\phi(\overline{1})$, simply because all group homomorphisms must preserve the identity element. this is all that I was saying/verifying in that paragraph; does that make sense?

Comment: yes! thank you!

Comment: @Math happy it helped! :)

Comment: @Math I'll write up answers to those questions later tonight, if that's alright :) (feel free to go through the rest of the proof and comment any other questions you have in the meantime, and I'll answer those too!)

Comment: Yes sure!  and I will complete reading your answer and tell you if I am stuck in any other parts.

Comment: @Math apologies, was a longer day than expected; I'll write up the details tomorrow

Comment: I think I figured out the answers to all my questions .... thank u!

Comment: @Math oh, that's great news! :) let me know if you have any further questions ~