# Why well-defined function sometimes means a group homomorphism function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

If we have the map $\phi_s$ that takes $\overline{1}\in\mathbb{Z}/p^a$ to $\overline{p^{s+b}/d}\in\mathbb{Z}/p^b$, where $d=\gcd(p^a,p^b)$. Why in order to see that $\phi_s$ is a well-defined map, we need to show that $\overline{p^a}\phi_s(\overline{1})=\overline{0}\in\mathbb{Z}/p^b$?

**EDIT:**

Is the meaning of well defined if we have $\mathbb Z_{n}'s$ as domain and target is just to send the identity to the identity?If so, for me, that definition of well defined is very different from the one ordinary used (if $x=y$ then $f(x) = f(y)$)

**Is there any connection between both definitions?**

Comment: I do not know why down voting the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the question implicitly requires the map to be an abelian group homomorphism, i.e. $\phi_s(x+y)=\phi_s(x)+\phi_s(y)$ for all $x,y$ in the domain. In particular, if we write $n\cdot x$ for $x+\ldots+x(n$ times$)$ (which is essentially viewing abelian groups as $\def\Z{\mathbb Z}\Z$-modules), then $\phi_s(n\cdot x)=n\cdot\phi_s(x)$. In this case it is the same as $\bar n\phi_s(x)$.

For the map to be well-defined, the problem is $\phi_s(\bar0)$. In $\Z/p^a\Z$, $\bar0=\bar{p^a}=p^a\cdot\bar1$. Hence $\bar0=\phi_s(\bar0)=\phi_s(p^a\cdot\bar1)=p^a\cdot\phi_s(\bar 1)=\bar p^a\phi_s(\bar 1)$, which is what you want to check.

Comment: So well defined in that case means an abelian group homomorphism? but how is well defined in that case related to our ordinary well-defined definition?

Comment: Since $\bar 1$ generates $\mathbb Z/p^a$, any abelian group homomorphism is determined by where it sends $\bar 1$. In other words, if you mandate where $\bar 1$ goes to, then that single requirement "induces" a unique homomorphism, i.e. $\bar n\mapsto n\cdot\bar 1$. This ensures uniqueness if it exists, but existence is ultimately guaranteed by well-defined-ness here: such a homomorphism might not exist if you chose a bad value.

Comment: @Math You can think of this as the rule of "inducing" a homomorphism makes the function potentially multi-valued (ill-defined). By definition $f(\bar 0)$ should be $\bar 0$, but a second possible value of $f(0)$ comes from "induction": $f(\bar 0)=f(\bar p^a)=p^a\cdot f(\bar 1)$. So you could say something like "$\bar 0=\bar p^a$, so $f(\bar 0)=f(\bar p^a)$.

Comment: but our function from $Z_p^a \rightarrow Z_p^b$

Comment: @Math I don't quite understand your confusion. $\bar 0=\bar p^a$ is an equation in $\def\Z{\mathbb Z}\Z/p^a\Z,$, and we want $f(\bar 0)=f(\bar p^a)$ to hold in $\Z/p^b\Z$.

Comment: Oh I see. but we usually equate 2 arbitrary elements in the domain and then try to reach that their images are equal .... but you are telling me equate specifically 2 representatives of the **element 0** and try to reach to the equality of their images

Comment: @Math One can actually show this is equivalent. In the most general form, we want $\forall m,n\in\def\Z{\mathbb Z}\Z, m\equiv n\pmod{p^a}$ implies $f(\bar m)=f(\bar n)$. Subtract $n$ from the first equation and then you reduce to the case of $n=0$. But then $m$ must be a multiple of $p^a$, and it will automatically hold if you only prove $m=p^a$ (by induction or otherwise).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117226/discussion-between-tesla-daybreak-and-math).